# Dialog problem: requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Tags: android, dialog

I'm creating a custom dialog containing an EditText so that I can get text data from the user:

```
final EditText newKey = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dialog_result);
AlertDialog.Builder keyBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(StegDroid.this);
keyBuilder
.setCancelable(false)
.setPositiveButton("Try Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        Log.v("Dialog","New Key: "+newKey.getText().toString());
    }
})
.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
       }
   });
AlertDialog dialog = keyBuilder.create();
dialog.setTitle("Decryption Failed");
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.decrypt_failed_dialog);
dialog.show();
```

However I always get this exception:

```
01-11 18:49:00.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3461): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
01-11 18:49:00.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3461):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:181)
01-11 18:49:00.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3461):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:199)
01-11 18:49:00.507: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3461):     at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:251)

...
```

at the line of `dialog.show()`. What should I be doing to get rid of this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to set the custom view before creating the dialog. Also you need to use `setView(View)` instead of `setContentView()` if you are using the default positive and negative buttons provided for you by the `AlertDialog`.

```
final EditText newKey = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dialog_result);
AlertDialog.Builder keyBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(StegDroid.this);
keyBuilder
.setCancelable(false)
.setPositiveButton("Try Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        Log.v("Dialog","New Key: "+newKey.getText().toString());
    }
})
.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
       }
   });
keyBuilder.setTitle("Decryption Failed");
keyBuilder.setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.decrypt_failed_dialog, null));
AlertDialog dialog = keyBuilder.create();
dialog.show();
```

Comment: It would be nice to add a comment so that someone else could easily figure out what was done differently without having to compare the code.

Comment: You are right dude... I have no time right now. Would you mind editing the answer to make it more precise?

Comment: Thanks! You saved my day with "...you need to use setView(View) instead of setContentView()..." :)

Comment: @Cristian When used in this way, it does not show positive and negative buttons. Any idea?

Answer (score 7):

I had an Alert dialog in my app and it used to give me this android runtime exception on android API 23.

Turned out this problem was with the import. I changed `android.app.AlertDialog` to `androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog` in the imports and the problem was solved.

This is for projects that use AndroidX Artifacts. Consider using the Support version `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog` if you are not using AndroidX.

Comment: Thank you!  I have been trying to figure this problem out for a couple of hours and noting worked until I saw your answer. Changing the import to androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog fixed it for me.

Answer (score 5):

Also make sure you are not returning an already-shown dialog. For example, `ProgressDialog` has a handy static method [`show()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html#show%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener%29) which takes some parameters and returns a `ProgressDialog`. Turns out you can't use that method and return the resulting `ProgressDialog`, because then when the OS tries to show it (and it's already shown), it will throw this same exception.

Beware, too: the above behavior is experienced on the Android emulator, but it actually did not throw an exception and worked just fine on my Droid Incredible running 2.2.

Answer (score 4):

I've ran into this about a year ago and fixed it in a way using weird code. Again, an app I'm working on has a fragment that should display normally on phone, but in a dialogue on tablet. I solved it like this:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private View mLayout;
    private ViewGroup mContainer;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mContainer = container;
        if (getShowsDialog()) {
            // one could return null here, or be nice and call super()
            return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        }
        return getLayout(inflater, container);
    }

    private View getLayout(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {
        mLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false);
        return mLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null)
                .setNeutralButton(R.string.filter_clear_selection, null)
                .setView(getLayout(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()), mContainer))
                .create()
            ;
    }
}
```

This allows me to add my fragment as any normal fragment (in a layout), but also display it as a dialog where it runs autonomously.

Answer (score 4):

For those who are having this problem specifically when using `DialogFragment`.

In my case, this was happened because I was extending the `DialogFragment` class incorrectly. I was returning a view on `onCreateView()` AND ALSO returning a custom dialog on `onCreateDialog()`. The documentation states:

> You might have a UI design in which you want a piece of the UI to
>   appear as a dialog in some situations, but as a full screen or
>   embedded fragment in others (perhaps depending on whether the device
>   is a large screen or small screen). The DialogFragment class offers
>   you this flexibility because it can still behave as an embeddable
>   Fragment.
>
> However, you cannot use AlertDialog.Builder or other Dialog objects to
>   build the dialog in this case. If you want the DialogFragment to be
>   embeddable, you must define the dialog's UI in a layout, then load the
>   layout in the onCreateView() callback.

Solved the problem by not creating anything on `onCreateDialog()` (only returning the superclass implementation).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. But my dialog was to be displayed for IME. When I switched to Dialog instead of AlertDialog, and omitted create, the program worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this error message when using a **DialogFragment**.

My problem was solved when in the `onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)` I changed the dialog that I returned

from

> `android.appAlertDialog`

to

> `androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog`

(or if you haven't migrate to AndroidX, then `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog`)

Answer (score 1):

This also happens if you try to access any view item with `findViewById()` before the `onCreate()` That is in my case i did:

```
 private class ShareViaDialog extends Dialog  {
 private ImageView mainSmallIcon = findViewById(R.id.mainSmallIcon);    //this is wrong
  @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}}
```

so the correct way to avoid this error is:

```
 private class ShareViaDialog extends Dialog  {
     private ImageView mainSmallIcon;
      @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mainSmallIcon = findViewById(R.id.mainSmallIcon); //should be here
    }}
```

Answer (score -3):

The exact way to solve this problem:

`requestFeature(int)` is a method of `Window`. You have to import this class (`android.view.Window`).

And you have to get the Window of the AlertDialog.Builder object. Then call `requestFeature(int)`. The input parameter is a constant of Window.

`keyBuilder.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);`