# AlertDialog can't show custom layout

Tags: android

I use the following code snippet to show a custom dialog:

```
btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // 1. Instantiate an AlertDialog.Builder with its constructor
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        // 2. Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog
        // characteristics
        builder.setTitle("Question");

        AlertDialog dialog= builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
                CallMethod();
            }

        }).setNegativeButton("No",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).create();
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.question);
        dialog.show();
    }
});
```

When I click the button, I get this exception:

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:229)
at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:234)
at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:337)
at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:355)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:260)
at com.example.MyApp.SimpleActivity$2.onClick(SimpleActivity.java:108)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4207)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17372)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What kind of request does it need?

Comment: Check here for custom alert dialog - androhub.com/android-alert-dialog/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippet is good, the error is this: the field **context** was *set* to another Activity. I changed it to the following and it works now:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SimpleActivity.this);
```

Your hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `setView` instead of `setContentView`:

```
dialog.setView(R.layout.question);
```

And set view before creating the dialog:

```
dialog.setView(R.layout.question).create();
```

**[Edit]**

```
 AlertDialog dialog= builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
  {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
    {
      dialog.dismiss();
      CallMethod();
    }

  }).setNegativeButton("No",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
      {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
          dialog.dismiss();
        }
      }).setView(R.layout.question).create();
```

Comment: There is no _create_ function for AlertDialog. Only AlertDialog.Builder has it and that doesn't work.

Comment: See the edited answer. I meant create method of Builder. Did you try like the one in the edited answer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the custom view before creating the dialog.

Try to use

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    .setTitle("Question")
    .setView()
    .setPositiveButton()
    .setNegativeButton()
    .create().show();
  }
});
```

Comment: If I do that _nothing_ happens when I click the button - no exception but also no dialog.

Comment: Changing the order doesn't change anything. The view is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

> android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content

You MUST place requestFeature before you set the content view. Example:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);
}
```

NOT:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
}
```

Comment: I don't use _requestWindowFeature_ so your answer does not help me.

Comment: Yep, it appears that this error is also thrown when you do not set the custom view before creating the dialog. See this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661459/dialog-problem-requestfeature-must-be-called-before-adding-content

Answer (score 0):

It is probably the best to write your own dialog class:

```
 private class CustomDialogClass extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener { 
public CustomDialogClass(Activity a, String picturename) {
        super(a);
        this.c = a;
        this.picturename = picturename;
```

...

set in the oncreate your layout:

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialoglayout);
```

and open it like this:

```
CustomDialogClass cdd = new CustomDialogClass();
                            cdd.getWindow());
                            cdd.show();
```